# Cannot overwrite OJLINTTASKCOLLECTION model once compiled, while creating multiple instances of "fawn" in nodejs using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Here is my mongodb connection using fawn

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Fawn = require("fawn");

module.exports = () => {
    const self = module.exports;
    mongoose
        .connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useCreateIndex: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useFindAndModify: false
        })
        .then(() => console.log("DB Connected"))
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(
                "Failed to connect to the database on startup - retrying in 5 sec"
            );
            setTimeout(self, 5000);
        });
        return Fawn.init(mongoose,'OJLINTTASKCOLLECTION ')
};
```

Although, I provided unique [collection name](https://github.com/e-oj/Fawn#fawn_init) to each app. I'm getting this error during compilation.

```
OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `OJLINTTASKCOLLECTION ` model once compiled.
```

I understand why this is happening, I am trying to instantiate fawn over a pre-existing instance. But how can I resolve it??

Answer (score 0):

**Why you are having the error:**

You get an `OverwriteModelError` error when you're trying to register a model with a given collection name more than once - [reference](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#error_Error-OverwriteModelError).

For clarity, you register(or create) a model is when you do something like this: `mongoose.model(<collection_name>, schema)`.

When you do:

```
Fawn.init(mongoose,'OJLINTTASKCOLLECTION ')
```

Fawn would internally try to register a model with `OJLINTTASKCOLLECTION` collection - [reference](https://github.com/e-oj/Fawn/blob/c3abcfc7868e2ad4ffc4576edf2dabd43e917bf8/lib/fawn.js#L41). Since this register operation is throwing an `OverwriteModelError`, it is most likely that you already registered a model with the `OJLINTTASKCOLLECTION` collection somewhere else in your code.

**The Fix**

Look through your mongoose setup and confirm that there is no other model registered on `OJLINTTASKCOLLECTION` collection, that should fix the problem.

Comment: It works on my machine, whatever i put the name of the collection. 
I pulled out this API code into another machine from GitHub, i changed the collection name there as mentioned in the [docs](https://github.com/e-oj/Fawn#fawn_init) but however, it throws `OverwriteModelError` during compilation